# How do I get ActiveSync or Windows Mobile Device Center to work in Windows 11 with my MC9190 scan gun?

Tags: windows-mobile, windows-ce

Ok, I know, these Motorola slash Symbol slash Zebra scan guns are really old, like over a decade old, and aren't in support anymore.  But I really like them (and they're available on the secondary market for cheap) for my inventory control system for my storage unit.

Microsoft doesn't publish WMDC anymore, and it hasn't been supported since Vista, and ActiveSync is consigned to the dustbin of Microsoft developer-centric products.  But is it really the only way to set up my MC9190 scan gun?  How do I install applications on it and transfer files?

Answer (score 4):

It can be done!

Juniper Systems, who make a replacement line of devices, continue to host the software and  published a fix for it.  Their guide is at https://junipersys.com/index.php/support/knowledge-base/support-knowledge-base-topics/desktop-connection-activesync-or-windows-mobile-device-center/wmdc-in-windows-10.

All of these links are in the Wayback Machine too, in case they stop.

Basically, download and install the final released version of WMDC (https://junipersys.com/data/support/drvupdate-amd64.exe).

Next, install the hotfix that makes it work in more recent versions of Windows (https://junipersys.com/data/support/WMDC-fixes-for-Win10.msi)

You may also need .NET 3.5.

[image: .net framework]

Reboot your computer, and then launch Windows Mobile Device Center from the start menu.  It will either sit there for a long time and quit, fail and ask to be reinstalled, or load.  If it doesn't load, close its processes in task manager and start it again.  Before it works properly for the first time, it will ask you to accept a license.

[image: Processes to kill]

If, connecting your device via USB (I have no idea if the Bluetooth or IR options can still  be made to work), it still does not show "connected" in WMDC, delete the "Microsoft Windows Mobile Remote Adapter", remove the scan gun from the cradle, and put it back in the cradle.  The device will come back, and work.

It should look like this:

[image: WMDC]

You probably don't need to "set up your device" given that it'll want to be connected to Exchange with ActiveSync and that's not so much a thing these days (and you probably don't want to use it as a phone, even though you kind of could).  "Connect without setting up your device" will allow you to copy files back and forth with Explorer and install programs.

In particular, the "Add/Remove Programs" option is in Programs and Services > More... > Add/Remove Programs.  File management is under File Management > Browse the contents of your device, and will open Explorer (you have to go through the menu).

---

So what's up with this "WMDC fixes for Win10" MSI?

Loading it up in ORCA (https://developer.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/downloads/windows-sdk/ and then run C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin...\x86\Orca-x86_en-us.msi) shows that it installs batch files that either open or close and then open WMDC, and sets up the following registry keys:

`HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows CE Services\AutoStartOnConnect\WmdcOpen` - open WMDC
`HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows CE Services\AutoStartOnDisonnect\WmdcCloseOpen` - close and open WMDC
`HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\RapiMgr\SvcHostSplitDisable` to 0x1
`HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\WcesComm\SvcHostSplitDisable` to 0x1

You may have to re-run this MSI after major Windows upgrades, but it's idempotent and fast.

---

What about this "sync center" business?

The device will show up there once the drivers are installed, but it's completely useless.  It's geared toward syncing files with a Windows Mobile phone, and you likely mostly want to install an SSH client or something.

---

And why is the mobile PC a network adapter?

.NET things, I guess.  It doesn't show up as a network interface one can Wireshark at, and it implements the Windows CE APIs using rapimgr.dll and wcescomm.dll.